# Server time in php script loaded on another host through iframe

Tags: php, iframe, time, cross-domain

I have PHP script on my server which will load on another server through an iframe.
In this script I'll give the server timestamp and store it using `time()` function.

**Now the question is:** where is the source of this time. time comes from `my server` or the `server which script loaded in`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ofcourse its from the script server, because it is inside an iframe

Comment: @phplover yes you are right, thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your script has no idea it's executed in an iframe.

Back to your question:

**The script will take the timestamp using the time of the server it's run on.**

Moreover, **time()** method returns a UNIX timestamp, which is timezone independed - see more info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php.

So, if you executed that on multiple servers, regardless on where you would call it, if servers has a correct time set, **you'll get the same timestamp on all servers**, regardless their timezones.

Comment: The best answer I could even give, hugely thanks bro